# Redirect only root directory to another site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm on a subdomain and only want to redirect from this subdomain shop.example.com to example.com, but I want all other urls from shop.example.com still to work and be kept. Like shop.example.com/checkout should not be affected by this rule only `/`

In the subdomain directory shop.example.com I tried this in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com
```

But then all is redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below rule, I am using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this has no effect for me it seems. I'm running this on shop.example.com

Comment: @matt did you have some other rule also working if has please show also try with clearing cache.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar I improved a bit your rule. Anyway, even the original was expected to work. @matt check that `mod_rewrite` is enabled as well as `htaccess` files allowed in your `shop` subdomain block config. Also, make sure there is no conflict with other rules somewhere (for instance, if you're using a framework)